# File inbound channel adapter process same file concurrently

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a requirement to process any file that is put in a specific folder. Those files can have same names. Later it will be processed by a proprietary bean that will rename the file extension based on the duplicate status of the filename (xxx.origin if the file has never been processed before or xxx.duplicate for the opposite condition).

Based on this requirement, I decided to use `file-inbound-channel-adapter`, with `spring-integration-3.0.8`. I set the `prevent-duplicates` attribute to `false`, so I can process all files. However, I found out that 1 file can being processed by 2 `file-inbound-channel-adapter` concurrently (even though the second adapter was created by accident - initialized twice in context and servlet). But this is a problem for me, because I actually intended to create more than 1 `file-inbound-channel-adapter` to process all files in the same folder and I get a result that 1 input file is being processed twice by 2 beans at the same time which got me 2 output file (xxx.origin and xxx.duplicate). I can't use `FileLocker` also, because the `file-to-string-transformer` can't work due to the lock status of the file.

Is there any way I can achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need multiple adapters polling the same directory - if you need to achieve concurrent processing, use a single adapter and add a task executor to the poller (or use an executor channel downstream).

If you must have multiple adapter instances, and you can use a newer version of Spring Integration (4.1.7 or higher, current version is 4.2.6) you can use a a shared `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` which is now a `ResettableFileListFilter` so when you rename the file you can remove it from the filter.

If you can't go to a newer version of Spring Integration, you will need a custom `FileListFilter` that allows you to remove the file after processing.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the response. I need multiple adapters polling the same directory because my idea is to have multiple beans to process a lot of files in a directory. So instead of 1 bean to process let's say 100 files, I want to use 4 beans so all files can be processed faster. Currently my configuration is file inbound adapter -> text to string transformer -> service activator -> file outbound adapter. The service activator is my proprietary bean to process the file. Therefore I think I must use 4 set of above configurations.

Comment: But you can achieve the same thing with a single adapter and a pooled task executor with 4 threads.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, what if the application is running in multiple servers (active-active)? Would you please recommend any approach to ensure that only one server will consume the file?

Comment: It seems this is the way to go: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-metadata-store

Comment: Yes; don't ask new questions on 4-year-old answers.

Comment: Hi Gary, I just raised a new SO thread as requested. See link above. Thank you!